# Subinterface on Cisco ASA 5550 does not work with VLAN on HP ProCurve

Tags: cisco, vlan, cisco-asa, hp-procurve

I created subinterface on Cisco ASA 5550 (ver. 9.7.1):

```
interface GigabitEthernet1/2.810
 vlan 810
 nameif dmz810
 security-level 50
 ip address 172.29.12.33 255.255.255.248
```

And VLAN 810 on HP ProCurve E5406zl (J8697A):

```
vlan 810
   name "DMZ810"
   tagged B2,B23-B24
   no ip address
   exit
```

VLANs are transmitted by GVRP, so we do not need to register them manually on each interface. I don't rigistered VLAN 810 (and many another DMZ) on ASA-HP links. Other networks work, but not VLAN 810. Tagged interfaces on switch - links to another switches.

For verification I assigned on VLAN 810 IP-address:

```
vlan 810
       name "DMZ810"
       tagged B2,B23-B24
       ip address 172.29.12.37 255.255.255.248
       exit
```

Bun they don't ping in both directions.

For example, this is a working subinterface and VLAN:

```
interface GigabitEthernet1/2.799
 vlan 799
 nameif dmz799
 security-level 50
 ip address 172.29.12.1 255.255.255.248 

vlan 799
   name "DMZ799"
   tagged B19,B23-B24,C13-C14
   no ip address
   exit
```

If I assign an IP address on VLAN 799, both interfaces will ping.

The limit on the number of VLAN is not exceeded.

What did I do wrong? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved. I registered VLAN 810 on two interfaces on switch to ASA (we have two devices ASA in stack failover). Don't trust GVRP. :-)

Comment: The fact is on a Cisco device, the VLAN doesn't come UP if there's no interface on which it is explicitly configured, or a non filtered trunk port. So my guess is, the VLAN was created but was down.

Comment: @Ruslan Please mark your answer so this post doesn't keep coming up until the end of time as unsolved.